# Where to store stored procedure/trigger/java classes?

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, h2

I do understand that H2 supports stored procedure/trigger/using java classes to extend the functionality.

But, where to put those classes (.class files/.jar files)?

If we have to put it in file system, then moving the database file without that classes, will make the stored procedure/trigger/etc useless. is it true?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures can be [stored as source code](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions); however this requires that a Java compiler is available. Triggers can't currently; so trigger classes must be in the server class path.

Comment: There are some helpful examples in `src/test/org/h2/samples`.